# .replace gives an error by adding span with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, html

I replace "Holla" to higlighted "Holla Hee" on the hole site with this code:

```
$("td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Holla','<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>'));
    }
});
```

but http://validator.w3.org gives the error:

> Error Line 205, Column 79: document type does not allow element "span" here

```
…s).html().replace('Holla','<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>'));
```

is there a other way? (can't save the script into an external js. file)

Comment: Are you sure it gives you error at replace line? it's possible to be for another html node

Comment: yes.. had to edit the question.. didn't show the span

Comment: @RaraituL i tried it by deleting this part! it's 100% the span in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `&lt; and &gt;`:

replace this:

```
 $(this).html($(this).html()
        .replace('Holla','<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>'));
```

with this:

```
$(this).html($(this).html()
       .replace('Holla','&lt;span class="txtWarn"&gt; Holla Hee &lt;/span&gt;'));
```

---

#### Update:

You can try with using variable:

```
var span = '<span class="txtWarn"> Holla Hee </span>';
$(this).html($(this).html().replace('Holla', span));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8URRY/)

Comment: ahhh.. no it doesn't work! code is valide but script doesn't work anymore

Comment: no.. its the same.. document type does not allow element "span" here! maybe there is a way to add this span another way?

Comment: another option is to change the `var` to `var span = '<'+'span class="txtWarn"> Holla Hee </'+'span'+'>';` Note the `+`

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in the `<head>` of the document you can try using CDATA

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function(){
       $("td").each(function () {
         if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Holla','<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>'));
         }
       });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

If you have only `Holla` in the `td` then another method could be using `.html()` to add the code.

```
$(function () {
    $("td").each(function () {
        var td = $(this);
        if (td.children().length == 0 && td.text() === 'Holla') {
            td.html('<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE that for this to work the `td` must look exactly like `<td>Holla</td>` and must not have any spaces.**

Comment: i have my script at the bottom of the page :(

Comment: same problem: document type does not allow element "span" here! td.html('<span class="txtWarn">Holla Hee</span>');